# spinner drop down implementation called from fragment to a new intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I have an app and I made an intent that is launched from a fragment.

However, my activity (which is an intent) runs into an error when i click the button in the fragment to start the customer player I have made.

the error is on this line:

```
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and this is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at blackstone.software.sunnahboxtvmenu.DuaatRadio.onCreate(DuaatRadio.java:52)
```

that is the line mentioned above.

I am unclear exactly how I miscoded the dropdown list that produced the error.

*** let me clarify: the channel selection in the drop down list is defined in an array list (in an xml) that lists all the channels.
The adapter in code takes the list and is supposed to populate it. However - it appears it is not being populated and thus the error.

It was working in a stand alone app just fine, but when i try to make it work in an intent spawned from a fragment (on a button click), I get the error listed above.

**** UPDATE:  Full code ****

Here is the code for the intent (in full):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
import static blackstone.software.sunnahboxtvmenu.R.string.app_name;

/**
 * Created by ironmantis7x on 10/26/15.
 */
public class DuaatRadio extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnPreparedListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public TextView songName, duration;
    private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
    private int forwardTime = 2000, backwardTime = 2000;
    private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    //String url = "http://radio.miraath.net:7000";
    //String url = new String[]{"http://radio.miraath.net:7000", "http://radio.miraath.net:7010", "http://radio.miraath.net:7020", "http://radio.miraath.net:7030","http://radio.miraath.net:7040", };
    String url;
    TextView radioInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set the layout of the Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String[] items = new String[]{"Masjid Tawheed Radio", "Masjid Rahmah Radio", "1st Muslim Mosque Radio", "Germantown Masjid Radio", "MPUBS Radio", "UK Dawah Radio"};
        String[] radioDescription = new String[]{"Masjid Tawheed (Atlanta, GA) lectures", "Masjid Rahmah (New Jersey) lectures", "1st Muslim Masjid (Pittsburgh, PA) lectures", "Germantown Masjid (Philadelphia, PA) lectures", "MPUBS (Trinadad and Tabago) lectures", "UK lectures"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        int channel = Arrays.asList((getResources().getStringArray(R.array.radios_array))).indexOf(app_name);

        //initialize views
        initializeViews();
    }

    public void initializeViews(){
        songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
        radioInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.radioInfo);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        //duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        songName.setText("Dawah Radio 24-7-12");

        seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
        seekbar.setClickable(false);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //mediaPlayer.release();

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the first item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                //url = "http://radio.miraath.net:7000";
                url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/6883149/shoutcast?force_http=true";
                radioInfo.setText("Masjid Al-tawheed Radio");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the second item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/6888856/shoutcast?force_http=true";
                radioInfo.setText("Masjid Rahmah (New Jersey)");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                //url = "http://radio.miraath.net:7020";
                url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/6877902/shoutcast?force_http=true";
                radioInfo.setText("al-Masjid al-Awwal(Pittsburgh)");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case 3:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                url = "http://api.spreaker.com/listen/episode/6545744/shoutcast?force_http=true";
                radioInfo.setText("Germantown Masjid (Philadelphia)");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                url = "http://mixlr.com/mpubs/showreel/those-who-rectify-themselves-and-the-people-when-the-people-become-corrupt-by-shaykh-mustafa-mubram/";
                radioInfo.setText("MPUBS (Trinadad and Tabago)");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            case 5:
                // Whatever you want to happen when the thrid item gets selected
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                //url = "http://radio.miraath.net:7040";
                url = "http://37.59.4.122:7040";
                radioInfo.setText("UK lectures");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    // play mp3 song
    public void play(View view)
    {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio selected. Buffering Now...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This may take a few moments. Please wait ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
        try
        {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                //mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }

            else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
        }

        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio not Available. Please try again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio not Available. Please try again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Radio not Available. Please try again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //handler to change seekBarTime
    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));
            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    // pause mp3 song
    public void pause(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Paused ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    // go forward at forwardTime seconds
    public void forward(View view) {
        //check if we can go forward at forwardTime seconds before song endes
        if ((timeElapsed + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed + forwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }
    }

    // go backwards at backwardTime seconds
    public void rewind(View view) {
        //check if we can go back at backwardTime seconds after song starts
        if ((timeElapsed - backwardTime) > 0) {
            timeElapsed = timeElapsed - backwardTime;

            //seek to the exact second of the track
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);

    }

}
```

Thanks.

ironmantis7x

Comment: Show full method code in which u are using posted block of code

Comment: @prosper K: I posted the full code of the android intent.

Comment: Does your "activity_main" contain Spinner with id "spinner1"?

Comment: no -- I am calling this intent from a fragment that has a button to click that starts the intent (the intent code is listed above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in Fragment, it's in `DuaatRadio Activity` code,

Here in this line

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

You are trying to get `dropdown Spinner` with id `spinner1` from `activity_main` layout. but it isn't defined there, so it will return null.

And in next line:

```
dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You are trying to `setAdapter` on `null object`. Which Result in `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I have to define it in the mainActivity?? I am calling the DuaatRadio Activity (as a new intent) from the fragment.  I am a little confused - so please help me understand.  Thanks!

Comment: "spinner1" Spinner must be define in "activity_main" layout.

Comment: in the xml? that would make it seem as if the drop down is the main layout and not part of the radio channel options where I want them. Cna yu please give details??

Comment: but that put's the spinner drop down list in the main activity, right?
the actual spinner is part of the radio which is defined in the duatradio intent (java class file) and it's corresponding xml. I am still confused -- i so apologize...

Comment: @ironmantis7x  So "activity_main" is not the right xml for DuaatRadio Activity? What is the corresponding xml for DuaatRadio Activity?

Comment: @ironmantis7x if "activity_main" isn't the correct xml then you should change this line **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** in your onCreate method.

Comment: aha!!
That was it!!! 
I completely forgot to switch that to the xml layout file where the actual drop down is at!! works like a charm now!!!!
ALL - the last comment by @Dhaval Patel i9s the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined your spinner in fragment class. So setting datas to spinner should be done in fragment class not in activity.